# Create a mess I need to clean up, while trying to solve conflicts between Macbook Pro M1 and Tensorflow library

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0, apple-m1

I have a 2021 Macbook pro M1.

It is a well recognized problem that it conflicts with Tensoflow library, see [here](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/48) or [here](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/51); in particular this last one was exactly the issue I experienced: when I tried to import tensorflow in jupyter notebook via the command

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

then the message

> The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

appeared. Then searching in the above linked discussions, I have the feeling that the suggestion given at some point, which points at [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-run-jupyter-notebooks-on-an-apple-m1-mac-ac3a8bf39c6c), **SEEMS** to be useful.

**FIRST QUESTION:** is this a/the solution for the M1-Tensorflow conflict?

I say "it seems" since before trying that I have been into the kind of tornado of desperate attempts leading a beginner like me to search for hints all around the web and then copy-paste commands taken here and there into the Terminal without understanding them all properly.

On one hand it sounds dumb, I admit, on the other the cost of understanding everything goes well beyond my humble intentions of learning some ML.

So, the final result is that I have a complete mess in my computer; the old libraries like numpy don't work anymore (when I import them inside a Python3 page opened with jupyter notebook with the command `import numpy as np`, the message

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

appears), then the pip command doesn't work, if I use the pip3 to install, nothing changes. I read somewhere to use a virtual enviroment, and I followed the instructions even if I wasn't really aware of what I was doing; I downloaded XCode, miniforge3...

Well, I guess that there is somebody out there who can relate with this.

**SECOND PROBLEM:** I would like to clean-up everything dealing with Python/pip/anaconda and so on and install everything from scratch, possibly following the above link to solve the M1-tensorflow conflict...if it is correct. How can I do that?

Can somebody help me, please? Thanks

Comment: Can you put the output of the `pip3 install numpy` command and `which python3`?

Comment: Also, did you -at some point- issued a command to remove something, like `brew uninstall python3`? This is a potential culprit.

Comment: You can try to reinstall pip and python3 if you deleted it with `brew install python3`.